# How to separate foreground text from noisy background in Python?

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, filtering

I am trying to extract the text from this image

[image: this image].

I tried adjusting contrast and brightness, smoothing (e.g. GaussianBlur, medianblur) and threshold techniques(e.g. Otsu) with OpenCV, there is still lots of remaining noise.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Easy. The text reads: `Birthplace LONDON, UNITED KINGDOM` and `Residence MILL BAY, BRITISH COLUMBIA` :D

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Yes, I converted it to a binary image using threshold methods, the result is not good. The background noise turns black.

Comment: Please always show your code. What threshold method did you use. There are several. Perhaps you also need to use some morphology and/or noise filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try a combination of Gaussian blurring, thresholding, and morphological operations to isolate the text. Here's a pipeline

Blur `->` Threshold `->` Opening `->` Dilation `->` Bitwise-and

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (7,7), 0)
thresh = cv2.threshold(blur, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (5,2))
opening = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel, iterations=3)

# Repair text
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (7,7))
dilate = cv2.dilate(opening, kernel, iterations=2)

# Bitwise-and with input image
result = cv2.bitwise_and(image,image,mask=dilate)
result[dilate==0] = (255,255,255)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('opening', opening)
cv2.imshow('dilate', dilate)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Answer (score 0):

If a more general solution is required, read on. Otherwise, you can refer to nathancy's answer, or plenty of other answers in this site.

---

I assume that

> extract the text from this image

means you want the text from this image as a string or the ROI of the text.

This is something called OCR (Optical Character Recognition) and is a pretty complicated deep learning problem specifically for the type of image you posted (noisy, low sharpness, low dynamic range etc.). If you are looking for a vanilla OpenCV library that can do this out of the box then, as far as I know, there isn't any.

Check these links for source code and explanation -

1. [OCR with pytesseract](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/09/17/opencv-ocr-and-text-recognition-with-tesseract/)
2. [Text ROI detection using EAST](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/20/opencv-text-detection-east-text-detector/)